# Could someone suggest a test automation tool to automate Java applet window?

Tags: java, applet, automation, gui-testing

Could someone suggest a test automation tool to automate Java applet window?
Require this to identify various buttons within the applet window too.

Answer (score 2):

I highly recommend [FEST](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/FEST/Testing+Applets) for all functional Java GUI testing, and yes it supports applets.

Comment: Can you provide an example demonstrating how FEST could be used to interact with an applet?