# How to control IE-hosted java applet programmatically?

Tags: java, c, internet-explorer, applet, java-native-interface

I've got a need to navigate java-applet programmatically and I am not that keen on Java platform. So lets assume I've got IE process stated with appropriate java applet loaded. Next I need to have some actions taken to this particular applet, like, lets say, sending WM_COMMAND to dialog along with BN_CLICKED code like I do with Windows in C. Assuming it's not a regular window I can refer to using HWND, I would like to ask someone for recommendations on how to do this.

Comment: Depending on what you want to do I would attempt to download the applet, decompile it and interact with it by including it in a Java program. If that's not a possibility, you can still try to download it and run it locally to get rid of having to run it within IE.

Comment: Ok. Maybe any other suitable idea on how to automate java applet? Any applet container? I don't want to decompile applet since I'm not java-developer and the time seems to be running out...

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have experience with any other ways. I however found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11342150/could-someone-suggest-a-test-automation-tool-to-automate-java-applet-window which suggests FEST, but that's also in java... I'm sorry I can't help you further.

Answer (score 2):

As I understand you want to navigate (sending keystrokes and mouse clicks) a java-applet on the client side. It depends if you own the applet (say: you have the code and can change it) or if the applet is closed source and you just want to remote it.

In the first case use javascript to automate it. Change the containing HTML page to include some Javascript and pass parameters to the applet as described in the [Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/invokingAppletMethodsFromJavaScript.html).

If the applet accepts parameters, but you cannot change the HTML page, use a [GreaseMonkey alternative for IE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greasemonkey#Equivalents_for_other_browsers).

Your other approach (sending Windows Messages from an extern application to IE) should also work. Start Spy++ (use the 64bit version if you are using a 64bit Windows), choose "Search - Find window..." and drag the "Finder Tool" icon over the applet and release it. You will see then the HWND and if you press search you will see the window inside IE window hierarchy.  So, yes you can send keystrokes and mouse clicks to a browser.

If I would automate the browser I would use [Geb](http://www.gebish.org/). You code a "web site test" in Groovy, just look at the Geb index page.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to record a navigation through the applet with FireFox + "Selenium IDE" then export it and try run it in a Java Application with the Selenium IE WebDriver.

Information about Selenium can be found here : http://docs.seleniumhq.org/

Maybe this question will also help you : [How to automate Java applet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10765682/how-to-automate-java-applet)