# how to Automate Java applet in browser

Tags: java, applet, automation, fest

i would like to know if there is a tool which can help me to automate a java applet application in browser
i tried to use FEST-Selenium but is there any other tools ?
thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could someone suggest a test automation tool to automate Java applet window?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11342150/3357935)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research on Java Applet Automation i found some tools which can help to automate the Java Applets. Some of them you can Look for is  [LiveConnect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Web/LiveConnect) and [Robot](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html). You can give a try with them.

Comment: Robot class seems interesting in my case thank you, but i must find a solution to automate robot with differents screen resolutions

Comment: Can you provide a code example of how these tools could be used?